# Convert 8 bit color to 24 bit color

Tags: colors, byte, bit

I was wondering if I can convert an 8-bit RGB color (1 byte = single color) into a 24-bit RGB color ((8 bits = red, 8 bits = green, 8 bits = blue) = single color). Is there a way it can be done? (I don't mind having only 256 colors). Also, if it would be possible can it be written as a formula/function in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convert_8_to_24(byte):
    byte = int(byte, 16)
    red = (byte >> 5) * 32
    green = ((byte & 28) >> 2) * 32
    blue = (byte & 3) * 64
    return (red, green, blue)

def convert_24_to_8(red, green, blue):
    byte = (floor((red / 32)) << 5) + (floor((green / 32)) << 2) + floor((blue / 64))
    byte = hex(byte)[2:]
    if len(byte) == 1:
        byte = "0" + byte
    return byte
```

Comment: While the quantization seems to be correct (it's 3x3x2 bit space, according to Wikipedia), the reverse computation doesn't yield a correct result. The reason is that if I want to convert a completely white image (all channels in RGB are 255 in value) into 8bit and then convert it back to 24bit, the result isn't exactly white. The resulting values are 224, 224 and 192 respectively, which isn't even a shade of grey. The correct formula must account for the colour shift and stretch the space so it fills the entire 24bit colour depth.